# Hyphenation of "something-to-something"

Tags: hyphenation

I would like to know how to correctly hyphenate the phrase "something1-to-something2", where *something2* is comprised of multiple words.

To clarify, here is the example where *something1* and *something2* are comprised of only one word each:
**node-to-surface** element

Example I am having problems with: **node-to-rigid flat surface** element.

How to correctly hyphenate in this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the whole sentence please, as it doesn't make much sense at the moment.

Comment: "Simplified node-to-rigid flat surface contact element was implemented in Matlab." Unfortunately, I cannot rewrite the phrase, I would just like to know how to hyphenate multiple phrases that are connected with -to-. Hope that helps.

Comment: I would avoid hyphenation in this case and say something like *"bla bla connecting (or relating) something1 to something2"*.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Usually it is simpler, like node-to-node element or node-to-surface element, but in this case "surface" needs to be "rigid flat surface".

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a hyphenated compound and one of the elements is already an hyphenated or open compound (that is, one with spaces between the words) use an en-dash for the wider compound:

> node–to–rigid flat surface
>
> node–to–rigid-flat-surface

(An exception being if you're hyphenating with a prefix (rather than an independent word) onto a hyphenated compound, then you might just use a hyphen).

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens are used to connect words which are linked to form adjectives placed before nouns.

> The report is up to date (no hyphens)
>  BUT
>  This is an
>   up-to-date report.

So in your sentence it would depend on which elements you thought were comprising the multi-word adjective in front of the noun.

They are used to distinguish elements which might otherwise cause confusion ([grammar-monster.com](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm)):

> ```
> a heavy-metal detector
> a heavy metal detector
> ```
>
> Both are correct, but they mean different things. The first device
>   detects heavy metals. The second device detects metal, and the device
>   is heavy.

It's hard to see how the words in your sentence would be misunderstood in this way. If they are simple adjectives you can just separate them with commas:

> Simplified node-to-rigid, flat surface contact element was implemented
>   in Matlab

Does this make sense, in context? But it's a fairly horrible sentence, brief to the point of incomprehensibility.

**EDIT**
Based on OP's comment and link below, it seems clear that the important compound elements are:

> node-to-node
> node-to-surface
> surface-to-surface

I think these elements should not be separated by other adjectives. Personally I would write:

> Simplified node-to-surface (rigid flat) contact element was
>   implemented in Matlab

You could then insert any other criteria from the table in the same way, eg *node-to-surface (thermal) contact element*.

Comment: I don't think so. I know it is hard to put the phrase into context since it is very specific. The way I put it is being used here http://mostreal.sk/html/guide_55/g-str/GSTR9.htm - I just wanted to make sure this is a correct way to write it since I need to use it in my paper.

Comment: That's clearer, thanks, please see my edit - I hope that works better.